# How can i move python functions into different .py file?

Tags: python, function, module

i want to move functions because of lot of files, into separate python files.
But if i do it, it dont work.

I tried:

File: server.py:

```
import os, cherrypy, json
from customers.py import *

class application(object):

def get_webpage(self):
....

def get_data(self):
....
```

File: customers.py:

```
import os, cherrypy, json

def get_customer_data(self):
....
```

I use the python as server,
the data in the function: get_customer_data is in this case not processed, get a 404 Not Found,
means the function is not included in main file (server.py)

Comment: How should we know? You haven't told us what's going wrong.

Comment: the data in the function: get_customer_data is not processed,
404 Not Found, means the function is not reachable

Comment: You need to show more detail. Note, though, that `get_customer_data` probably doesn't need a `self` parameter, since it isn't a method of a class.

Answer (score 1):

I removed the self from get_webpages() because it was not indented, which means it was not part of the class.

application.py:

```
class application(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

def get_webpage():
    print('From application')
```

customers.py:

```
from application import *
get_webpage()               #  From application
```

You could indent get_webpages() and make it part of the class. The way you call it would change. (I put the self back and capitalized the name of the class.)

application.py:

```
class Application(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def get_webpage(self):
        print('From application')
```

customers.py:

```
from application import *

a = Application()
a.get_webpage()             #  From application
```